# How to add counter to multiple elements with the same class

Tags: javascript

I am trying to recreate the WoW talent calculator as seen here - https://classicdb.ch/?talent#h

Project files - https://codepen.io/jjchrisdiehl/pen/gNQLgR

This is a project to help better understand Javascript, so please avoid any jQuery workarounds for this - thanks.

If you look at the HTML code, you'll see I have the HTML set up as div's with the class 'item' and then I have another div nested inside of the 'item' div with the class 'points'.

```
<div class="item two nature_wispsplode button" data-max="5">
   <div class="points"></div>
</div>
<div class="item three fire_fireball button" data-max="3">
    <div class="points"></div>
</div>
```

The idea is to append a Javascript event listener called logMouseButton to every div with the class 'item'. This will listen for a click and log whether it was a left or right mouse click.

```
/* Get item div element for addEventListener*/
let itemButton = document.getElementsByClassName("item");

/* Apply logMouseButton to every itemButton */
for (var i = 0; i < itemButton.length; i++) {
  itemButton[i].addEventListener("mouseup", logMouseButton, false);
}
```

Now the logMouseButton code was hacked from the Moz page on MouseEvents .button. My thoughts are to use a switch to manage adding or subtracting points to each item's individual counters.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button

```
/* Set Counter */
var counter = 0;

/* Add or subtract points based on button clicked */

function logMouseButton(e) {

/* Set the max number of clicks in points counter based off of data-max attribute */
  var maxPoints = this.getAttribute("data-max");

  if (typeof e === "object") {
    switch (e.button) {
      case 0:
        if (counter == 0 || counter < maxPoints) {
          counter = counter + 1;
        }
        document.querySelector(".item .points").innerHTML = counter;
       // alert(counter);
        break;

      case 1:
        log.textContent = "Middle button clicked.";
        break;

      case 2:
        if (counter > 0) {
          counter = counter - 1;
        }
        document.querySelector(".item .points").innerHTML = counter;
        break;
      default:
        log.textContent = `Unknown button code: ${btnCode}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Left click increments, right click decrements. As you can see in my codepen project, the right/left clicks work, but only for one item.

**My question is - how would I apply this to each item individually so that they manage their own counter independently of the other items?**

Thanks!

*Note* - I managed to get the counters working with some direction from klugjo. I ended up logging the HTML value of 'points', incrementing the value, then adding the new value back to the innerHTML: https://codepen.io/jjchrisdiehl/pen/JgXzKe

If you have any insights as to why this isnt the best way to do it, or why another way is better, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the div that corresponds to the element that was clicked.

Using `document.querySelector(".item .points")` will always select the first element in the DOM.

You can use `e.target` to access the element that was clicked, and since what you need is the only child of that element, you can replace

```
document.querySelector(".item .points").innerHTML = counter;
```

with

```
e.target.children[0].innerHTML = counter;
```

Then you will run into another issue, which is that your counter is global and common to all the buttons.

So you will have to use a hashmap (JS Object) instead of a single integer for `counter`

```
var counter = {};
```

Comment: Hey there, great ideas! Would it be possible to just change the scope of the counter or is the map necessary to "remember" all of the separate counters values?

Comment: If you change the scope, the variable will be destroyed each time. But you can for example retrieve it directly from the HTML div itself

Comment: Interesting. So would it be possible to simply have the counter value begin at zero, increment the counter, set the new value within the HTML div, then log the new counter value by reading the specific divs value again for each subsequent click? Essentially storing the value of the counter within the HTML itself?

Comment: Yes that would be possible. You can read the value with `e.target.children[0].innerHTML` as well. The value will be a string so use `parseInt` to convert it to an integer

Answer (score 0):

An approach is to select the `.item` elements and create an `array` of `.item` length (number of `.item` elements in the page) to store the counter for each one individually.

Here's a demo, it contains some helpful comments :

```js
/** selecting the elements with ".item" class and declaring an array to store each element counter separately **/
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item'),
      countArr = new Array(items.length);

/** loop through the elements and add "mouseup" listener (to ensure catching both left and right clicks) for each element  **/
 
/** 
* el: the current element from the ".item" elements collection
* i: the index of that elemnt in the collection
**/

items.forEach((el, i) => {
  countArr[i] = 0; /** initialize each array element with 0 so we can count later (new Array puts "undefined" as the array elements values) **/
  
  /** add the "mouseup" listener **/
  el.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    let txtCount = el.querySelector('.count'); /** selecting the "span" that contains the counter from the current elemnt (don't forget that we're looping in ".item" elements collection) **/
    if(e.which === 1) countArr[i]++; /** left click **/
    else if(e.which === 3) countArr[i]--; /** right click **/
    txtCount.textContent = countArr[i]; /** update the "span" wih the calculated counter as left click adds 1 and right click removes 1 from the counter of each element **/
  });
});
```

```css
/** basic styling for the demo **/

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 15px 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  user-select: none;
}

.item .count {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">counter = <span class="count">0</span></div>
<div class="item">counter = <span class="count">0</span></div>
<div class="item">counter = <span class="count">0</span></div>
```